# Proving covariance equals zero given a specific conditional expectation

Tags: covariance, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to prove the following:

Given $[| = ] = []$ for any value of $\beta$, prove that $\operatorname{Cov}(,) = 0$;

So I was thinking to start with the definition of $\operatorname{Cov}(,)$ and use the tower rule that is $[] = [[|]$, such that:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(, ) = [( − []) ⋅ ( − [])] = [[( − []) ⋅ ( − [])|]].$$

However, I am not sure this leads me anywhere and how to continue from here.

Comment: You're on the right track. If you multiply out the expression for the covariance you get $cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X] \cdot E[Y]$. If you can show the first part equals the second, you are done, and you can do that by using the tower rule on $E[XY].$

Comment: So I can write [] as [[|]] . How can I simplify this further to show that it equals []⋅[]?

Comment: A key property of conditional expectations is the following: $E[f(Y)\cdot X|Y] = f(Y)E[X|Y]$ for any function of Y. Conditional on Y, the value of some function of Y isn't a random variable but a constant, and can be taken out of the expectation

Comment: (, ) = [] - []⋅[] = [[|]] - []⋅[] = [[|]] - []⋅[] = [[]] - []⋅[] = []⋅[] - []⋅[]  = 0; 
Thank you very much for the very helpful guidance.